# Select Coordinates from Google Maps in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-maps

I'm looking at a way to bring up a map in Google Sheets where I can select a location and have cells populated with the selected locations coordinates.

ie, Etihad Stadium in Melbourne has coordinates -37.816700, 144.947495. I'd like to be able to bring up a map, click on Etihad Stadium and have cell A1 show -37.816700, 144.947495.

Is there any function/script etc. that will allow me to do this in a Google Sheet?

Comment: Just curious if anyone has come across any solutions yet? I have a couple of uses for it if it's possible to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I took a short virtual walk from the Etihad in Google *Earth* and the exported KML file was over 1,000 lines (for a 1/2hr walk) so presumably not a viable solution for you.

However, you mention cell A1 rather than, for example, ColumnA, so a manual process might be acceptable, provided not subject to error from keying coordinates with lots of decimal places.

So, if you paste the link (click on Share) to Etihad Stadium from Google Maps into A1:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Etihad+Stadium/@-37.8165604,144.9453114,419m/am=t/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x6ad65d452b97c1ef:0xf0456760532d9f0!8m2!3d-37.8165647!4d144.9475055
```

and then delete all up to and including `3d` and `!4d` what you should be left with is:

```
 -37.8165647 144.9475055
```

which when searched in Google Maps shows a pin just on the circumference of the centre circle, or in Google Earth:

[image: Earth]